Bulilding Javafx with Firebase into Jar
I have been trying for two weeks now to build my javafx and firebase project into jar. Firstly when i build the normal projec into jar and run it without firebase and google cloud dependecy it works but when add these dependencies to it and build it into jar then i get this message.
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes
        at java.base/sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.processImpl(SignatureFileVerifier.java:340)
        at java.base/sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.process(SignatureFileVerifier.java:282)
        at java.base/java.util.jar.JarVerifier.processEntry(JarVerifier.java:327)
        at java.base/java.util.jar.JarVerifier.update(JarVerifier.java:239)
        at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.initializeVerifier(JarFile.java:760)
        at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.ensureInitialization(JarFile.java:1058)
        at java.base/java.util.jar.JavaUtilJarAccessImpl.ensureInitialization(JavaUtilJarAccessImpl.java:72)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath$JarLoader$2.getManifest(URLClassPath.java:883)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:848)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:760)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:681)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:639)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:495)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:474)
        at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.loadMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:790)
        at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:685)

meanwhile i have tried maven shade plugins and and do everything but still getting this error. I am using intellij IDEA and using artifacts to build my jar.  For clarity this is my pom.xml file and i am sure there is default problem with Javafx and firebase integration or this is a trick i am not getting. This is the pom.xml file
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>FuelStationManagementSystem</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <!-- Java and JavaFX versions -->
        <maven.compiler.source>19</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>19</maven.compiler.target>
        <javafx.version>19</javafx.version>
        <firebase-admin.version>9.1.0</firebase-admin.version>
        <google-http-client.version>1.42.2</google-http-client.version>
        <grpc.version>1.49.2</grpc.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- JavaFX Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-deploy-lib</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Firebase Admin SDK -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
            <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
            <version>${firebase-admin.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude duplicate Google HTTP Client and related libraries -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
                    <artifactId>google-http-client</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
                    <artifactId>google-http-client-gson</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
                    <artifactId>google-http-client-apache-v2</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <!-- Exclude duplicate gRPC dependencies -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
                    <artifactId>grpc-netty-shaded</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
                    <artifactId>grpc-alts</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Explicitly define required dependencies to avoid conflicts -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-http-client</artifactId>
            <version>${google-http-client.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-core</artifactId>
            <version>${grpc.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-api</artifactId>
            <version>${grpc.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.9.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.9.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Compiler Plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                    <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- JavaFX Maven Plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>8.8.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.example.fuelstationmanagementsystem.HelloApplication</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Shade Plugin for creating an executable JAR -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>com.example.fuelstationmanagementsystem.HelloApplication</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>


Have you verified the filter is working? Execute jar tf <jarfile> to see if the signature files have been excluded as expected. Also, it's not clear to me whether you're using Maven or using IntelliJ to create the JAR file. Are you seeing this error with the JAR file created by executing mvn package (or ./mvnw package if using the wrapper)?

zenjava maven plugin is obsolete, replaced by openjfx maven plugin.  Shaded jars for JavaFX are not supported, though you may be able to get them to work.  Instead other options are shipping multiple jars rather than shading, or using jlink if your project is modular or jpackage if not. GraalVM may also work, though I have not tried it.
